# Postman fails to upload file using s3 pre signed url

Tags: node.js, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman

I am trying to upload a media file (image with any extension jpg/png/jpeg or a video) to aws s3 bucket from the postman i created my pre-signed url in my backend as following

```
const params = {
        Bucket: 'safarni',
        Key: 'posts/Photo.png',
        Expires: 30* 60,
        ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream'
    }

return await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
```

This successfully generates a url but I can't seem to test it using postman
this is screenshots to how I adjust the request in postman

[image]

[image]
[image]

**What i tried** :

1- I added cors policy to my bucket and the credentials I am using is for IAM user whom i allowed put/*

2-I tried different file extensions but still the same error

**Edit**

I tried adding the signature version v4 to params in the above code and it throwed me an error saying unexpected key.I even tried adding it to aws config and s3 but nothing happened

Comment: You have to use PUT instead of POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass these signature values in Authorization. Looks like the keys are mismatched.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

A guess, maybe im wrong,
Sharing this might help, aws use signature version 4 for all regions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

Check this thread this might help
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1663

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I tried it but unforetunatly nothing worked. Check my edit

Comment: hmm..try to whitelist your ip ? let see, can you check the logs